# Amazon CloudFront Directory Path as Origin Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am quite new to Amazon CloudFront and I am struggling to achieve a couple of solutions. I have large, medium and small images sitting on our S3 bucket, that have the same names but sit in different folders according to their dimension/size. I am trying to achieve the following:

I want to display the directory path as the origin name, similiar to internal routing for URI but I just can not seem to find a solution. I have read in the documentation that it is possible but I am struggling. The paths should be as https://name.cloudfront.net/p_image_large/file1.jpg and https://name.cloudfront.net/p_image_medium/file1.jpg and https://name.cloudfront.net/p_image_small/file1.jpg.

As you can you see the file1.jpg is the same name but we have different sizes in different folders.

CloudFront is displaying the image as https://name.cloudfront.net/file1.jpg which is not how I want it. In Nginx I have got this working like an alias based on the Request URI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what "sitting in different paths" means, exactly.  The normal configuration in CloudFront is to leave Origin Path empty.  If the object in the bucket is `https://example-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/p_image_large/file1.jpg` then the origin path should be blank.  If it's at some other path, please clarify what you're trying to accomplish, with more examples.

Comment: *I want to display the directory path as the origin name* is unclear, too.  The origin name is not visible from the browser... it's only used internally by CloudFront.

Comment: You should Leave the Origin Path field empty in the settings. And try to navigate the file with `https://name.cloudfront.net/p_image_large/file1.jpg`. this should work. It will display the path in title.